# NHibernate HQL Group by Entity

Tags: nhibernate, hql

Is it possible to run a query similar to this one in HQL without having to specify all of the column names.

```
select med, MAX(med.PrescriptionLines.Prescription.PrescriptionDate)
    from Medication med
    where med.Patient.PatientId = :patientId
    group by med
```

This query expands out all of the properties of the Medication object in the select, but in the group by only expands med to be med.MedicationId.  I don't want to have to specify all of the properties of the medication object in the group by clause.  Is there a way to do it?

I've tried replacing the **group by med** with **group by med.*** or **group by {med.*}** but that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not implemented. See:

- https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-528
- http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1615 (this issue is over three years old)

Comment: The first link you send suggests that this was resolved in 1.2.0.  this is clearly not the case, as I'm using 2.0.1.

Comment: Nope, take a good look, it says the *docs* were fixed to reflect the reality that it's *not* supported

Comment: As much as I hate it, it's the right answer.  Seems amazing that they haven't implemented it yet, or made it possible to do it (ie. \{med.\*\}).  Thanks.